# Javascript - contenteditable split element and parents in half

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, contenteditable, content-editor

I'm am working on a micro wysiwyg editor. I need to be able to do the following:

Lets say the content within the editor looks like so:

```
<p>This is 
    <strong>some content 
        <span>and more</span>
    </strong>
</p>
```

If I put the cursor on the space in `and more` and click a button, I want the HTML to split like this:

```
<p>This is 
    <strong>some content 
        <span>and</span>
    </strong>
</p> 

** CURSOR IS HERE NOW **

<p>
    <strong>
        <span> more</span>
    </strong>
</p>
```

How would I go about doing this? I can already get the anchor node of the clicked element and have a method to get the root parent but no idea how to approach splitting the elements as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `p` element to the cursor position, and then remove it immediately. The automation of the content editable will take care of the possible splitted formatting (or which ever) tags, and the produced HTML will be valid. Like so:

```js
    var but = document.getElementById('splitBut');
    but.addEventListener('click', function () {
     var temp;
     document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<p id="temp"></p>');
        temp = document.getElementById('temp');
        temp.parentElement.removeChild(temp);
   });
```

```html
<button id="splitBut">Split</button>
<div id="pad" contenteditable>
    <p>This is
        <strong>some content 
        <span>and more</span>
    </strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpmmm6Ly/1/).

Notice, that this code doesn't work in any version of Internet Explorer (works in Edge, though). Also, the produced HTML might vary, depending on the used browser.

---

**Edit**

Chrome seems to have issues with the HTML insertion. The inserted element must be empty. After removing the element, Chrome adds a `br` element, and renders the contenteditable incorrectly (a candidate to add to the [Inconsistencies list](https://github.com/guardian/scribe/blob/master/BROWSERINCONSISTENCIES.md) of `document.execCommand`?). Unfortenately I couldn't fix this, and the answer is useful only when run in FireFox or Edge.